# Talend sequence Generation with Data

Tags: talend

I Have generated my own sequence based on the data. I need to compare the current sequence with the previous sequence generated from the data.

If both the sequences are same I should not increment the value. If the sequence are different I need to increment the sequence  by using `Numeric.sequence` system routine. How to do that?

Example :

1. Generated sequence --1234567890 --1
2. Next sequence      --1234567890 --1

If Both has the sequence number generated the value should remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Store the previous sequence in a variable in order for you to be able to compare, instead of comparing now == next, in talend you need to do now == previous for you to be able to compare both.

For this a tJavaRow should be enough, you can store the previous sequence on a global variable,  and compare it in the next iteration

Comment: i have done that by creating a user rountine for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have a lookup on the target filter the sequence if same

```
  tmap

 SOURCE (row1) -> filter 
 (if(row1.sequence !=row2.sequence))
                               >insert out
            ^
            |
            ^
 Target (Lookup row2)
```